# Avoidng skipped frames in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android

My app queries a web server for data to display, and I save all of this data in the outState Bundle in onSaveInstanceState() to make sure I don't have to requery the data after every screen rotation. However, on every screen rotation I now get LogCat errors saying "Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.", and I think it's because off all of the data I'm bundling up in onSaveInstanceState(). I moved the unbundlinng of the data in onCreate() into an AsyncTask to help with similar problems there, but I don't know if I can do the same in onSaveInstanceState() without the activity ending before the data is saved. Is there a proper way to save all of the web data on screen rotations without causing skipped frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're storing a lot of data in Serializable objects, you should consider having the classes representing your data implement Parcelable, as it's considerably more efficient for packing/unpacking.

http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/